# Two Different types of Arrays into the first Array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have created a `ArrayList<Student>` in a object `StudentList list1` that is `saving[Serialization]` a student's information (`name,id,age,gpa,etc`) into the `list1`, so that the `list1[0] = 1st student's info`, then the `list1[1] = 2nd student's info` and so on.

Also a new `ArrayList<Subject>` in a object `SubjectList list2` for all subject of a student at index 0 example `list2[0]=(java,math,etc)` [for first student] `list2[1]=(c++,english,etc)` [for second student] saved in a file.

I *want to add the subject next to the student info*:

> list1 index[0]=1st Student info, index[1]=1st Student's Subjects.
>   index[2]=1st Student info,index[3]=1st Student's Subjects.

I am stuck with this simple problem.Help please.

```
package studentPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        Student s = new Student(null, null, null, null);
        s.stulist.add(new Student("Smith", "1", "M", "3"));
        s.stulist.add(new Student("Jenny", "2", "F", "4"));
        s.stulist.add(new Student("Roger", "3", "M", "2"));     
        System.out.println(""+s.stulist);
        for(int i=0;i<s.stulist.size();i++){
            Student search = s.stulist.get(i);
            if(search.toString().contains("Jenny")){
                System.out.println("Found"+i);
                s.addSubject(s.new Subject("OOP","007"));
                s.addSubjects(s.sublist);
                System.out.println(""+s.stulist.get(i)+""+s.sublist);
            }
            else System.out.println("Not Found"+i);
        }
                System.out.println(""+s.stulist);
    }
}

package studentPanel;

import java.util.*;

public class Student {
    public String name, id, gender, cgpa;

    ArrayList<Subject> sublist = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    ArrayList<Student> stulist = new ArrayList<Student>();  
    public void addSubject(Subject new_subject) {
        sublist.add(new_subject);
    }
    public void addSubjects(List<Subject> subjects_list) {
        for (Subject s : subjects_list)
            addSubject(s);
    }   
    public Student(String name, String id, String gender, String cgpa) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\tID: " + id + "\tGender: " + gender + "\tCGPA: " + 

cgpa+ "\n";
    }
    public class Subject {
        public String cname,cid;
        public Subject(String cname, String cid) {
            this.cname = cname;
            this.cid = cid;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Course: " + cname + "\tCode: " + cid;
        }
    }
}
```

I just can't get it right, it was suppose to add the subject `s.addSubject(s.new Subject

("OOP","007"));` to the student Jenny.

Output Should be like:

> [Name: Smith  ID: 1   Gender: M   CGPA: 3
>
> , Name: Jenny ID: 2   Gender: F   CGPA: 4
>
> , Name: Roger ID: 3   Gender: M   CGPA: 2 ]
>
> Not Found0
>
> Found1
>
> [ Name: Jenny ID: 2   Gender: F   CGPA: 4 ][Course: OOP,Code: 007]
>
> Not Found2
>
> [Name: Smith  ID: 1   Gender: M   CGPA: 3
>
> , Name: Jenny ID: 2   Gender: F   CGPA: 4 [Course: OOP,Code: 007]
>
> , Name: Roger ID: 3   Gender: M   CGPA: 2 ]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 2 lists. One populated with Student objects, and the other with String objects. And you wish to add these to a new list where newlist[evens] = Students and newlist[odds] = Strings. Is this correct?

Comment: If your code is too messy to post, create a short but complete example which *isn't* too messy to post...

Comment: Why don't you add the subject information to the student information?

Comment: @JonSkeet may be i can attach the *.java files here.don't know how yet.

Comment: @rsp that is what i am trying to do. Simple program "add student name add subjects show the student info while ask add more subjects to that student" that's it just like a course registration options.

Comment: You shouldn't add different objects to the same list - prone to errors and bugs. See @ArnabDatta for the correct way to handle this

Comment: @Tamim: No, you don't attach a file here - you edit the contents into your question. See the help when editing for more information. But make sure it's a short example which only contains what it needs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the approach you should be taking is something akin to this :

```
class Student{ 
   private String name, ID;
   private int gpa, age;
   //More personalia stuff...

   private ArrayList<Subject> subjects;

   public void addSubject (Subject new_subject) { subjects.add(new_subject); }
   public void addSubjects (List <Subject> subjects_list) {
       for (Subject s : subjects_list) addSubject(s);
   }

   //Getters 
   public int getGPA() { return gpa; }
   public int getAge() { return age; }
   public String getName() { return name; }

   //.. More personalia getters

   //Setters 
   public void setGPA(int new_gpa) { gpa = new_gpa; }



 }

class Subject { 
    String description;
    String ID;

}
```

---

Now if you have a list of students say :

```
 ArrayList <Student> all_students;
```

Here you can go through the list and add subjects to any or all of them.

Edit : added some getters and setters that makes it clearer how you access object info.

---

Edit 2 to address your updated post :
There are a number of issues with your code. Let's go through them from the most high-level stuff to low (not the same as importance mind you)

**1) Class names** 
A class should not be called "Main". It is unclear what the class is. Instead, call it what it is : a student-subject-registry system. `class StudentRegister` should be just fine.

**2) Class contents**
You included the class `Subject` as an inner class in `Student`. This does not make sense, as a subject is not a part of a student (in literal terms in real life). This is not the worst part of it though; having `Subject` as an inner class will make you create loads of identical subjects for each and every student. This is completely redundant.

Now you also included a list of all students in every Student object. Is this intentional? If so, it seems a bit misguided. Student `A` does not need to, and probably will never know about all other students. Not to mention, everytime you add a new student N, you'll need to add `N` to all student objects that currently exist. That is redundant as well.

---

**A proposed solution**

Let's think about what you know as a student. You know :

- your age (private int age)
- your GPA (private int GPA)
- your ID  (private String ID)
- your name (private String name)
- the list of subjects you take (private List  subjects)

*Note that you as a student have no control over what the course description and ID is*

All those private variables are private because those are things that you as a student disclose on request of someone. It is akin to someone asking you "What's your name?" or "What's your age?" etc. This is what you accomplish by implementing getters like `getName()` , `getAge()`.

Now let's consider the part in italic. When someone asks you what courses you are taking, you simply refer to the list of courses that are common for you and other students that are enrolled at the universities. You do not create your own courses that nobody else knows about. Therefore, a Subject should not be an inner class in your Student class. It is instead a referance (i.e a pointer) to a course object that is offered by the university (continue reading for further explanation)

Now consider a course object. That course object does not need to know about :

- the list of students that are enrolled in a given year
- any other subjects

Any given course object needs to know :

- it's course description
- course ID
- a string representation (i.e what you've implemented as toString() )

Finally, in your `StudentRegistry` class, you should have two lists now :
 - a list of students enrolled at the university : `List <Student> all_students;`
 - a list of all subjects/courses offered        : `List  all_subjects;

Remember that each students have methods for adding subjects? You simply refer to the course objects that exist in the studentRegistry and ask each student to add those to their subject list. **No new subject objects will be created.** Any and all subjects in every student's study plan will refer to objects in the `all_subjects` list contained in the StudentRegistry class

Comment: pasting code in comment is unreadable. please post it as an edit to your original question

Comment: A. Correct me if i am wrong.

1. Main should be as class StudentRegister or any other relative name.
2. class StudentRegister contains a fixed Courselist and a nonfixed Studentlist(New Comer).
3. a) Student's personal info always (name,etc) always private.
   b) I wanted all info as Strings. problem arise while asking age but user typed "ABCD". I know there is Exception method for that. don't know well.
4. "Is this intentional?" I guess you mean this
`ArrayList<Student> stulist = new ArrayList<Student>();`
not intentional. Need to be in StudentRegister right?

Comment: B. How to save without `cout.writeObject(this);`?
5. Methods for adding subjects how to save it with that student.I used save to save the Studentlists as follow.
`public void save() throws IOException {`
....
`cout.writeObject(this);`
`cout.close();`
}

Comment: Need to save the "Studentlist" with their subjects in a single file. Don't know how to save two different list in a file just like the output. that is the main reason i wanted the one combined array for those two different types of arrays in first place. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A. 1. There should be a main ** method **, not a class called main. There is a big difference. 
A. 3. Read up on Java I/O (both file and terminal)
A. 4. Yes this is what I mean. Yes it should be in StudentRegister

B. Again, read up on Java I/O to/from File. You simply iterate over one list first and then the other and print out their `toString()` representations to a file.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two different problems.

**Your first problem:**

The first one is that you have a list and you want to put different objects in that list (a student-object and a subject-object). You can do this in two different ways. The first way is to use the list simply with objects: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();` After that you can add everything to the list but you have also to cast everything - that's not a good solution. The second and better solution is to  provide a common interface for both objects. For example something called  `IInformation` that your classes implement. But it could be hard to find a suitable interface for a student-object and a subject-object. But that's a matter of your creativity.

**Your second problem:**

Now to your second problem. I think your design, architecture or just the way you want to do it is wrong. What is your problem? Why you want to put the information in a list behind the the student? Is there a good reason for that? I think there are better solutions. Your student-object can hold the subject-infomation for example. That would be logical. I as a student know the subjects that I'm studying. Another way is to create a third object that holds the mapping between student and subject (i.e the relation):

```
class Relation {

private Student student;
private Subject subject;
}
```

You can then store such an object in your list.

Comment: As i said to @rsp it's it just like a course registration options.
while i want to search the student by name or id. then add the subject to that particular student only. total process need to create only one file for Student list.

Comment: @TamimZubair you said the solution yourself. You want to add the subject to the particular student. Then provide a method in the student class like new Student().addSubject(subject). The answer from Arnab Datta is doing that quite good. The serialization into a file is another tobic (but no problem btw).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the add method of the List class that also takes an index.

Take a look at [the method javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29).